# null value in column "name" of relation "contact_contact" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django

## DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, miarisoa00@yahoo.de, , null).

```
IntegrityError at /contact/contact/
null value in column "name" of relation "contact_contact" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, miarisoa00@yahoo.de, , null).
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/contact/
Django Version: 3.2.15
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
null value in column "name" of relation "contact_contact" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, miarisoa00@yahoo.de, , null).
Exception Location: D:\MKSD_SITE\MKSD_WEB\site\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  D:\MKSD_SITE\MKSD_WEB\site\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.13
Python Path:    
['D:\\MKSD_SITE\\MKSD_WEB\\site\\src',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39',
 'D:\\MKSD_SITE\\MKSD_WEB\\site',
 'D:\\MKSD_SITE\\MKSD_WEB\\site\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 04 Jun 2023 16:39:42 +0000
```

**views.py**

```
def Kontact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact = Contact()
        message_name    = request.POST.get('message-name')
        from_email      = request.POST.get('from-email')
        ville           = request.POST.get('ville')
        message         = request.POST.get('message')

        contact.name = message_name 
        contact.email = from_email
        ville           = ville
        contact.subject = message  

        contact.save()

        message = f"""  

        Name: {message_name}
        From: {from_email}
        Stadt: {ville}

        New message: \n\n{message}

        """

        # Send email
        send_mail(
            message_name, #subject
            message, #message
            from_email, #from email
            ['kontakt.mksd@gmail.com'], #to email
            fail_silently=False, 

            )


        return render(request, 'contact.html', {'message_name': message_name})

    else:
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {})
```

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    ville = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=355)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Template - HTML**

```html
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" class="was-validated">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="col-lg-6">Email (erforderlich):
            <input type="email" name="from-email" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">Phone
            <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="yours">
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-6">Name (erforderlich):
            <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">Stadt
            <input type="stadt" name="stadt" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder=" City">
        </div>                                  

        <br><br><br>
        <div class="col-12">
            <textarea name="text" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="text">
            </textarea>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12 my-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                Send
            </button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could somebody please help me by solving this problem? I am stucking over one day to search what I have done wrong but still in difficuty.

Comment: The error says that the value 'name' that you're trying to add to a DB is null. See if name is set to None when the db is updated.

Comment: Don't use `request.POST.get`, the best way to validate data is through a Django Form, and if that is impossible use `request.POST[..]`, just making the error fail silently is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the input element is `name`, not `message-name`, the same with `ville` which is `stadt` and `message` which is `text` in your HTML form, so you use:

```
# views.py:
def kontakt(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message_name = request.POST['name']
        from_email = request.POST['from-email']
        ville = request.POST['stadt']
        message = request.POST['text']
        Contact.objects.create(
            name=message_name, email=from_email, ville=ville, subject=message
        )
        message = f"""  

        Name: {message_name}
        From: {from_email}
        Stadt: {ville}

        New message: \n\n{message}

        """

        # Send email
        send_mail(
            message_name,  # subject
            message,  # message
            from_email,  # from email
            ['kontakt.mksd@gmail.com'],  # to email
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')

    else:
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {})
```

It is often a *bad* idea to use multiple (natural) languages concurrently. You seem to partly English, German and French, making it all very confusing.

---

> **Note**: Please use `request.POST['ville']` over `request.POST.get('ville')`. Using `.get(…)` often only silences the error, but not the problem: indeed it will work if the key is missing. But if the value for that key is really required, it will only result in more trouble later in the process.

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thank you all very much. It works perfectly now.
Have a nice day.